# How to Select Model Parameters for Transformer (Heads, number of layers, etc)

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, hyperparameter-optimization, attention, gpt

Is there a general guideline on how the Transformer model parameters should be selected, or the range of these parameters that should be included in a hyperparameter sweep?

- Number of heads
- Number of encoder & decoder layers
- Size of transformer model (`d_model` in Pytorch)
- Size of hidden layers

Are there general guidelines like number of decoder layers should be equal to encoder layers? Thank you